# How to test sidekiq perform method return with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Hello guys I do not know how to test that sidekiq worker perform method return a call of another class method

I have this sedekiq worker

```
module Payments
  module Bitso
    class ProcessPaymentWorker
      include Sidekiq::Worker
      sidekiq_options queue: 'default'
      def perform(options)
        Users::Payments::Bitso::Disperse.new(options).call
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I have tried this spec but the code coverage is marked as not covered `Users::Payments::Bitso::Disperse.new(options).call`

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'sidekiq/testing'
Sidekiq::Testing.fake!

RSpec.describe Payments::Bitso::ProcessPaymentWorker, type: :worker do
  let(:options) { { foo: 'bar' } }

  describe 'worker' do
    it 'should enqueue jobs' do
      expect { described_class.perform_async(options) }.to change(described_class.jobs, :size).by(1)
    end
  end

  describe '#perform' do
    let(:disperse) { class_double(Users::Payments::Bitso::Disperse) }

    it 'should call disperse' do
      allow(described_class).to receive(:perform_async).with(options).and_return(disperse)
    end
  end
end
```

How should I test `Users::Payments::Bitso::Disperse.new(options).call` to mark my spec coverage at 100%?

Answer (score 0):

The assertion (`expect`) in the test is missing. Also, you're testing the instance method, so you probably want an `instance_double`.
Something like this should work.

```
  describe '#perform' do
    let(:disperse) { instance_double(Users::Payments::Bitso::Disperse) }

    it 'should call disperse' do
      expect(Users::Payments::Bitso::Disperse).to receive(:new).with(options).and_return(disperse)
      expect(disperse).to receive(:call)
      described_class.new.perform
    end
  end
```